# How to dynamically Order a listbox with a dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox with 20 colors.  It looks something like this:

1:Red
2:Green
3:Blue
4:Orange
5:Red
6:Yellow
7:Orange
8:Red
9:Green
....

It gets the data from an ObjectDataSource which in turn gets it's data from a method which returns a datatable.  I want a dropdown which basically has 2 items, Order By # and Order By Color.  If the user chooses Order By #, it will Order the ListBox in ascending or descending order.  If the user chooses Order By Color, it will Order By Color.  How do I go about doing this?

Can I sort this using a DataView?

Thanks,
XaiSoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the sort expression to your ObjectDataSource as a Select parameter, you can define it like so:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="SelectMethod" 
        TypeName="MyDataObject">
            <asp:Parameter Direction="input" Type="string" Name="sortExpression">
            </asp:Parameter>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then in the "SelectMethod" method where the data is retrieved add a parameter of that name and return a DataView:

```
    public DataView SelectMethod(string sortExpression)
    {
        DataTable table = GetData();
        DataView dv = new DataView(table);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression;
        return dv;
    }
```

Then in the wizard for the ObjectDataSource you can bind that Parameter to the dropdown SelectedValue.  Make the value of each of the DropDown items the same as your column names.

Comment: I will give this a shot as well as the JavaScript way and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I have more than 1 SortExpression.

Comment: look at the DataView Sort property documentation.  You can provide a string like "Color ASC, Number DESC" to sort by first Color ASC, then Number DESC.  The method I describes works because the Sort defaults to ASC, so if you just pass a column name it will sort on that column Ascending.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm assuming you've already figured out how to bind the ListBox in the first place.)

Set the property AutoPostback="true" on your DropdownList. This will cause the SelectedIndexChanged event to fire when the user picks a different value.

In there you can rebind your listbox.

---

**Edit:** deleted my misunderstanding around the ObjectDataSource - joshperry's answer covers that much better!

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot.  What is this syntax you are using.  Is it LINQ?

Comment: This is LINQ, yes. Make sure you have using System.Linq; at the top of your code file or it won't compile.

If you're using an older version of the .NET framework or and older version of Visual Studio, LINQ won't be available to you, in which case you'll need to use another method to sort your list.

Answer (score 1):

Just wonder... You already have the data in the ListBox, why not sorting it using javascript? To avoid go back to the server and ask for the same thing.

just get the correct list box id and you're done!

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function sortlist() {
    var lb = document.getElementById('mylist'); // <-- Use $get(<%# myList.ClientID %>); if you want
    arrTexts = new Array();

    for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
      arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text;
    }

    arrTexts.sort();
    // arrTexts.reverse()  // <-- uncomment if you want descending

    for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
      lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
      lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
    }
  }
</script>


<select name="mylist" id="mylist" size="5">
  <option value="Anton">Anton</option>
  <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
  <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
  <option value="Bill">Bill</option>
  <option value="Carl">Carl</option>
</select>
<br />
<a href="javascript:sortlist();">sort</a>
```